alguien me podría instruir a implementar lo siguiente?
Alguien me podría recomendar o ayudar de alguna manera de mandar notificaciones push, estoy desarrollando un app en la cual implementare un chat pero quiero que le mandé notificaciones en cuanto mande cualquier mensaje ya sea de cualquiera que responda en el chat.
Pero en cuanto quiera hacer mi APK también quiero que dichas notificaciones se sigan mandando y sin necesidad de una segunda aplicación como en el caso de Expo.
De ante mano gracias por su atención

¿Qué has logrado hasta el momento? Este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas sobre problemas concretos de programación. O sea, tienes que tener un código más o menos funcionando con el cual trabajar.

Por favor, lee el [tour] y [ask] para saber como funciona el sitio primero. Además, quieres hacer una APK? Esto es para android? Deberías comenzar pequeño, solo con el sistema de notificaciones push, y un video tutorial de lo que usas.
